# MongoDb aggregate inconsisted result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following MongoDb query. All five of the Guid's specified in the query, is present in the document. Furthermore all five of them has the correct region code as specified.

```js
db.Offers.aggregate([
{
    "$match": {
        "OfferId": {
            "$in": [
                "DD3B57A3-5183-4FF8-9E3C-321F4298B58D",
                "C60E9CC5-7339-479E-8003-285F6BD195C7",
                "392951DD-5BCB-42F2-B1E9-C96180A0C01B",
                "1B6263C0-B8FD-4706-98DB-89D2ACE5C1BF",
                "0126406E-FF5B-448E-AFFB-6D253C4C720C"
            ]
        },
        "Region": "ZA"
    }
}
])
```

But for some reason it only four of the five records. When I remove some of the existing Guid's, it will return the one that was skipped initially.

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong or not understanding?
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried querying the same with find instead of aggregate, just to get the idea what's not working right query or aggregate.

Comment: @Arun, many thanks for the response. My MongoDb skills are in it's infant stages, so I'll have to run a couple of tests

Comment: $match stage should run exactly like a query inside find, this should work, maybe show us the actual documents just in case?